# How read all the bytes of the pending response before close Java TCP socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Client is sending some byte[] of data to server and server should send some byte[] of response. Immediately client sends reconnect request and after connects it continue sending next messages and after again client send reset request, it is a loop. It is happening exactly same. But where as i have a scenario that client sends data to server to reset the server socket connection. server also sends back response to client. During that time client socket is disconnects and not able to read response which server sends.

I ran in a loop of 150 times but 4 time is not got response due to above scenario.

note that i am using read(byte[] data) method in a loop.

Is there any solution that read all the bytes of the pending responses before close Java TCP socket from client side.?

Comment: Code is much easier to understand than an abstract description of code.  Consider editing your question and showing us your code.

Comment: Sorry i am unable to share code as its high restricted. Just i need to know that, Is there any method in socket api to read all pending responses before closing socket. ? i used readFully(byte[] data) also, but its not working

Comment: It sounds like your client should not close the connection until it has received the reset acknowledgement from the server.